# System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Amazon.EC2.Model.GroupIdentifier]

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-powershell

trying export security groups but getting this in csv

System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Amazon.EC2.Model.GroupIdentifier]

any idea why? I think its because it cant export and array. but how do I convert this line to string

$ec2.SecurityGroups

I tried $ec2.SecurityGroups -join ", " and it wont do it

```
$results = @()

$ec2instances = get-ec2instance

$ec2list = $ec2instances.Instances

 

foreach ($ec2 in $ec2list) {

$result = "" | select Name, InstanceId, Platform, AMI, InstanceType, PrivateIpAddress, SecurityGroups, AvailabilityZone

$result.Name = ($ec2 | select-object -expandProperty tags | where-object -property Key -eq Name).value

$result.InstanceId = $ec2.InstanceId

$result.Platform = $ec2.Platform

$result.AMI = $ec2.ImageId

$result.InstanceType = $ec2.InstanceType

$result.PrivateIpAddress = $ec2.PrivateIpAddress

$result.SecurityGroups = $ec2.SecurityGroups

$result.AvailabilityZone = $ec2.placement.AvailabilityZone

$results += $result

}

 

#$results | ft -autosize

$results | export-csv -NoTypeinformation -USeculture aws_ec2_report.csv -Force
```

Answer (score 0):

ok figured this out with

```
$result.SecurityGroups = ($ec2.SecurityGroups.groupname -join " | ")
```